# What is the Difference between TemplateColumn and TemplateField?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagrid

What are the real differences between the two and what are the advantages in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use `GridViewRow row in DataGridCoAuthoring.Rows` instead of datagrid.items. apart from that you can use both  with the same functionality in datagrid and gridview.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually they are the same; TemplateField is for the GridView, and I guess TemplateColumn is for the DataGrid control.  They are not interchangable; they are just used for different controls.

Comment: Yes i too think same. in that case can you tell me what is the equivalent of "datagrid.items" property in gridview control. i need this because now i am workin in changing a datagrid control to gridview control.

Comment: As you seen from @sms, GridView.Rows is the collection of rows.  A row is nothing but the equivalent of an Item in the DataGrid, with each one having specific columns that can be retrieved by index.

Answer (score 1):

**Template Column:**

Use the TemplateColumn column type in a DataGrid control to create a column with a customized control layout. You can provide a custom appearance for the heading section, the footer section, and the items section of the column by using the HeaderTemplate, FooterTemplate, and ItemTemplate properties, respectively. You can also control how an item being edited is displayed in the TemplateColumn object by setting the EditItemTemplate property.

**TemplateField** :

The TemplateField class is used by data-bound controls (such as GridView and DetailsView) to display custom content for each record displayed. When you need to display content in a data-bound control that is not provided by one of the predefined data control fields (such as BoundField), use the TemplateField class to create your custom user interface (UI). The TemplateField object is displayed differently depending on the data-bound control in which it is used. For example, the GridView control displays a TemplateField object as a column, and the DetailsView control displays it as a row.

for more information, you can see [Template Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Template Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)